# Beside every Option in bootstrap multiple-select, i need a text field

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Beside every Option in bootstrap multiple-select, i need a text field which will be entered if that option is checked.

Right now i have a multiple select, where i want to add a amount text field associated with it.[image: Multiple select]

The code for my multiple select is below-

```
 <select data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" class="ruleparameter selectpicker" multiple
                                            name="PROVINCE_CD_RP_OVCC">
                                        <option>NL</option>
                                        <option>NS</option>
                                        <option>PE</option>
                                        <option>NB</option>
                                        <option>QC</option>
                                        <option>ON</option>

                                    </select>
```

Comment: Probably rethink your design and use some form of collection or list instead of a select...

Answer (score 0):

Example Dropdown with Multiple checkbox select with jQuery:

```
https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri
```

I'm sure you want to see this.

Let me know if this helpful for you!

Comment: I want a text field for every option in the multipleselect.